# "ant all" build unable to continue. 'Cannot run program "java".'

Tags: java, linux, bash, ant, centos

My system is CentOS 6.4. The package I'm trying to build is the latest version of OpenGTS. The problem I'm having is that upon executing *ant all* I'm getting the following output:

```
[root@OpenGTS OpenGTS_2.5.0]# ant all
Buildfile: /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/build

custom.jar:
     [echo] Skipping General Custom build ...

customtrack.jar:
     [echo] Skipping Track Custom build ...

custom:

prepare:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/build/lib
     [echo] OS = Linux
     [echo] JavaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/build.xml:182: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre"): java.                                                                                       io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

My environment variables are all defined correctly but from what I can tell, the build wants to execute *java* inside of the jre directory. Currently, I can only execute it from inside the binary directory. Should I modify .bashrc so I can execute *java* from any directory? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaHome should be pointing to your JDK, not your JRE ... Shouldn't it? You could try including jdkhome environment variable as well, pointing to the JDK and see if that over rides it...

Comment: set your PATH to include your jdk/bin folder

Comment: @MadProgrammer I had the same thought but the install guide explicitly states to use the JDK and not the JRE.

Comment: @SajanChandran That solved the problem. The build continued without issue. Thank you!

Comment: @deeperDATA you say that the install guide says to use the JDK and not the JRE, but you're using the JRE?

Comment: Well, it is using the JRE directory inside of the openJDK directory. This is my variable:

JavaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre

I'm not sure if that is technically JDK or JRE but it is definitely the specific path it instructed me to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your PATH to include jdk/bin folder